# How to add dynamic value from xml request in response xml file in wiremock json?

Tags: xml, wiremock

I have wiremock mapping json like

```
{
      "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "/getrelation",
        "bodyPatterns": [
          {
            "matchesXPath": "//ns:RelationId[contains()='0123']",
            "xPathNamespaces": {
              "ns": "http://www.example.com/XY/getRelationRequest/3/Req"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "bodyFileName": "getRelationResponse.xml",
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "text/xml"
        }
      }
    }
```

I want to pass value received in xml request in element RelationId to RelationId element in response xml file(getRelationResponse.xml). Can somebody please tell me how to do it? We can use response-template but most of the examples are for in line json body.

I tried using below code in getRelationResponse.xml

```
<rpy:RelationId>{{{xPath request.body '//ns:RelationId[text()]'}}}</rpy:RelationId>
```

But this did not work as syntax seems to be wrong.

I want to replace '000000011' with value from xml request.
**getRelationResponse.xml**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <rpy:getRelationRequest_Rpy xmlns:rpy="http://www.example.com/XY/getRelationRequest/3/Rpy">
            <rpy:Relations>
                <rpy:Relation>
                    <rpy:RelationId>000000011</rpy:RelationId>
                </rpy:Relation>
            </rpy:Relations>
        </rpy:getRelationRequest_Rpy>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer without knowing what `(getRelationRequest.xml` looks like. Please edit your question and add a short, representative sample of the xml file.

Comment: Yes I have added the file in the question

Comment: That's better, but your sample xml doesn't contain any `RelationId` which has a value of `0123`. Did you mean `000000011`?

Comment: Which I shared is the content of response file. May be my file naming is not correct.  So if request matches with "//ns:RelationId[contains()='0123']",  values of ns:RelationId should be extracted from the request and should be placed in "<rpy:RelationId>000000011</rpy:RelationId>". Here, 000000011 is just an example. That value should be replaced with the value from request.

Comment: Did you enable response templating when starting up WireMock?

Comment: @Tom I tried adding below lines in response mapping `"transformers": ["response-template"],
        "transformerParameters" : {
          "relation_id" : "//ns:RelationId[text()]"
        }` . I accessed relation_id parameter using `{{parameters.relation_id}}`. This works but I think //ns:RelationId[text()] this is wrong as this statement does not populate any value. I see '//ns:RelationId[text()]' as is in the response xml.

Comment: I also came across this [link](https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock/issues/1554) So not sure if it is possible to achieve what I want.

Comment: You also need to enable response templating at startup. Adding the transformer to the stub in the way you've shown means you need to have started with local response templating enabled.